# Oracle Database: how to move table create$java$LOB$TABLE into a new table space, this table has a LOB column

Tags: oracle

I need move table create$java$LOB$TABLE (only has 1 row data, and 1 column is LOB column) in a user schema to new table sapce, Why can't I drop it and recreate it with the data saved from exp?

Comment: Why not just re-create in new tablespace and drop the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to drop it if you only want to [move it](http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-move-lob-data-to-another.html).

```
ALTER TABLE ... MOVE
```

amd

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MOVE LOB(lob_columnname) STORE AS (TABLESPACE new_tablespace_name);
```

Comment: okay, since the table was created by a java procedure as my co-worker told me, so it can't just simpling be moved or drop it, then recreated from sql DDL definition.

Comment: It doesn't matter what external program issued the CREATE TABLE command. All Oracle sees is the SQL.

Comment: I agree, but my co-worker said it is not that simple, so I am a bit confused. So you have done it and it worked fine?

Comment: Since I moved it using the traditional way, never found out why why my co-worker warned me on it, so I think the traditional way is fine. Thanks!